# Navbar is blocking me from clicking on anchor links and buttons

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website and am facing a problem. Somehow, my navbar is preventing me from clicking on anchor links and buttons throughout the website. Specifically, in the reproducible example in the link below, the two links, "See my blog" and "Hello there" are not working. I have been messing with the z-index, and the links and buttons start working, but then the navbar buttons does not work. My code can be viewed [here on Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/profmush/pen/BavZrzd).

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <div class="menu-bar">
        <div class="menu-logo">TITLE</div>
        <img id="menu-open-btn" class="menu-btn" src="assets/media/menu-btn/open-menu-btn.svg" />
        <img id="menu-close-btn" class="menu-btn" src="assets/media/menu-btn/close-menu-btn.svg" />
    </div>

    <ul id="menu-links">
        <li><a href="/" class="menu-link">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about" class="menu-link">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/blog" class="menu-link">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact" class="menu-link">Contact Me</a></li>
        <div class="social-media-box">
            <a href="https://github.com/kumarhimself"><img class="social-media-icon" src="assets/media/social-media/github.svg" /></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/kumar-himself/"><img class="social-media-icon" src="assets/media/social-media/linkedin.svg" /></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/kumarhimself/"><img class="social-media-icon" src="assets/media/social-media/instagram.svg" /></a>
        </div>
    </ul>
</nav>

<section id="hero-section">
    <div class="hero-content">
        <img class="hero-img" src="assets/media/hero-img.jpeg" />
        <div class="hero-title">Hello, my name is <span class="hero-name">NAME</span></div>
        <p>Some lorem</p>
        <a href="/blog" class="btn-primary">See my Blog</a>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">Hello there</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

/* General Settings */
/* Color Palette */
/* Width Breakpoints */
/* Misc */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf");
  font-weight: 300;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("assets/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
  font-weight: 100;
}
html {
  scroll-margin-top: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.text-gradient {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ff2c00, #fa0362);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.bg-gradient {
  background: hsl(10, 100%, 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(10, 100%, 50%) 0%, hsl(338, 98%, 49%) 80%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(10, 100%, 50%) 0%, hsl(338, 98%, 49%) 80%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(10, 100%, 50%) 0%, hsl(338, 98%, 49%) 80%);
}

/* Partials */
body {
  background-color: #001e47;
  color: #fff;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.2rem;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

.menu-logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 1rem;
  color: #ff2c00;
}

.menu-btn {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(1%) hue-rotate(277deg) brightness(101%) contrast(101%);
}

#menu-close-btn {
  display: none;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4.5rem;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  transition: color 0.5s;
}

.menu-link:hover {
  color: #ff2c00;
}

.social-media-icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  filter: invert(100%) sepia(100%) saturate(1%) hue-rotate(277deg) brightness(101%) contrast(101%);
  transition: filter 0.5s;
}

.social-media-icon:hover {
  filter: invert(26%) sepia(54%) saturate(4805%) hue-rotate(359deg) brightness(98%) contrast(111%);
}

/* Pages */
#hero-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hero-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.hero-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  clip-path: circle(40%);
}

.hero-title {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.hero-name {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ff2c00;
}
```